# What php version allows this?

Tags: php, oop, class, variables

`$var = a_function_that_returns_a_object()->property->something;`

in old PHP versions you had to do this:

```
$obj = a_function_that_returns_a_object();
$var = $obj->property->something;
```

So from which PHP version does the first code work, without giving me a error ?
I know that in 5.3 works because I'm using it, but I want to know in what version it starts to break

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with PHP 5, method chaining is supported.